# Bootstrap select input area bigger than parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

So my bootstrap select's area is bigger than I'd like when it's on small screens (mobile). So I was wondering if there was some way to force the selection area to not be bigger than the parent.

My problem via image below as well as recreated issue in snippet. The black bar represents edge of screen.

[image]

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all",
  success: (data) =>
  {
    let select = $("#select-country");
    for (let country of data)
    {
      select.append(`
          <option>
            ${country.name}
          </option>
        `);
    }
    $(select).prop('disabled', false);
    $(select).selectpicker('refresh');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div style="width: 300px;">
    <select id='select-country' disabled="true" className="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Choose a country">
    </select>
</div>
<div style="width: 50px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: black; z-index: 200">
</div>
```

Comment: try adding ` .bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li a span.text { 
    white-space: normal;
}` to your css.the option text width create the problem.

Comment: @XYZ kind of annoying how there's no built in property :\

Comment: Does that css helped?

Comment: @XYZ yeah, it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
.dropdown-menu
{
max-width:100%;
}
```

hope this helps..