# Constrain content of Bootstrap Select content to columns its container is constrained by

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

I have a [`bootstrap-select`](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#width) component the content of which is expanding beyond the grid the button that triggers it is conforming to. It actually goes completely off the page:

**Markup (Django templating, but that isn't relevant I don't think):**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select
        class="selectpicker form-control"
        data-title="Please select"
      >
        {% for item in items %}
        <option
          data-content="
            <div>
              <div>
                <i class='fa {{ item.icon }}'></i>
                <h4-text'>{{ item.title }}</h4>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p class='text'>{{ item.very_long_text }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>"
        ></option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Removing the `item.very_long_text` (`p.text`) node solves the problem and the grid is adhered to so that is definitely the problem. I have tried to apply the following styles to that node in order to control the problem but it persists:

- width: auto;
- width: 100%;
- overflow-wrap: break-word;
- overflow-wrap: normal;
- word-break: break-all;
- color: red;
- white-space: [every available value];
- word-wrap: break-word;

In fact, the only solution that works is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44383260/1252748):

```
.dropdown-menu {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

But that seems really sloppy to me to override a Bootstrap class that is—from what I understand—meant<sup>†</sup> to work the way that I want it to in the first place.

#### How can I confine the content of this select menu to grid columns its trigger is confined by?

<sup><sup>†</sup> The section I've linked to in the Boostrap Select documentation makes this clear IMO</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the content is expanding the grid because by default, bootstrap dropdown menu items have their `white-space` set to `nowrap`. Resetting this to `normal` by for example applying a class to every `data-content` item seems to fix this issue. Below is a minimal repro.

```js
$('select').selectpicker();
```

```css
.fix {
  white-space: normal
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" data-title="Please select">
  <option title="Option 1"
    data-content="
      <div class='fix'>
        <div>
          <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i>
          <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>"
  ></option>
  <option title="Option 2"
    data-content="
      <div class='fix'>
        <div>
          <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i>
          <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>"
  ></option>
  <option title="Option 3"
    data-content="
      <div class='fix'>
        <div>
          <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i>
          <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>"
  ></option>
</select>
```